# Spring Security 3.2.3 RELEASE with JavaConfig

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

I have a Spring Security configured in XML that works just fine. Now, I'm trying to have it expressed in JavaConfig only so as to get rid of the XML configuration altogether.

I've looked at the reference documentation, and at many blogs and support requests, but I still cannot find the solution.

It gives me the following exception:

```
Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.config.WebTestConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain;
```

Pitifully I resorted to post my own request here...

The code:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest" })
public class WebTestConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

}

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}

public class WebInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebInit.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        registerListener(servletContext);

        registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);

        registerJspServlet(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
        // Create the root application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = createContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class, WebSecurityConfiguration.class);

        // Set the application display name
        appContext.setDisplayName("LearnInTouch");

        // Create the Spring Container shared by all servlets and filters
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));
    }

    private void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = createContext(WebConfiguration.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        Set<String> mappingConflicts = dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        if (!mappingConflicts.isEmpty()) {
          for (String mappingConflict : mappingConflicts) {
            logger.error("Mapping conflict: " + mappingConflict);
          }
          throw new IllegalStateException(
              "The servlet cannot be mapped to '/'");
        }
    }

    private void registerJspServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext createContext(final Class... modules) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(modules);
        return appContext;
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public DelegatingFilterProxy springSecurityFilterChain() {
        DelegatingFilterProxy filterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
        return filterProxy;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN").and().httpBasic();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/login", "/admin/logout", "/admin/denied").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/admin/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/list")
        .failureUrl("/admin/denied?failed=true")
        .and()
        .rememberMe();

        http.logout().logoutUrl("/admin/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/login").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
    }

}
```

The XML configuration that I hope to get rid of:

```xml
<!-- A REST authentication -->
<http use-expressions="true" pattern="/admin/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <logout />
</http>

<!-- A form based browser authentication -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/denied" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <form-login
        login-page="/admin/login"
        default-target-url="/admin/list"
        authentication-failure-url="/admin/denied?failed=true"
        always-use-default-target="true" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/admin/login" />
    <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>

<!-- A custom authentication provider on legacy data -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

**UPDATE:**

I added a Configuration directive:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

and an explicit import directive:

```java
@Import({ SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.class })
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

But the exception remained the exact same.

I'm running Spring Security 3.2.4.RELEASE and Spring 3.2.9.RELEASE

If you have any suggestion, it is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed this bean definition from the security configuration and it seems to have solved the issue

```
@Bean
public DelegatingFilterProxy springSecurityFilterChain() {
    DelegatingFilterProxy filterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
    return filterProxy;
}
```